# react-native run-android command stuck on task app:installdebug

Tags: react-native, adb

Trying to install application to device using command react-native run-android.

No errors are shown, but app gets stuck onTask app:installDebug producing follwing output.

> Task :app:installDebug
>   08:46:24 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>   08:46:24 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on ‘xxxxxxxxxx’ : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   08:46:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'WAS-LX1 - 8.0.0' for app:debug
>   08:46:24 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device ‘xxxxxxxx’
>   08:46:24 D/Device: Uploading file onto device ‘xxxxxxxxxxxx’
>   08:46:24 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/xxxxx/work/xxxx-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
>   08:46:25 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   <============-> 99% EXECUTING [1m 20s]
>   :app:installDebug

After about three 3 minutes follwing error is thrown:

> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>    com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException

Tried ./gradlew clean, reinstalling node_modules. 
Adb device command shows device name.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app using `adb uninstall com.your-org.your-packagename`? Sometimes there's a version mismatch between what you're trying to install and what is installed already.

Comment: I did not do that. My solution was to reset factory settings. If the problem appears again, I will try that. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me, for the same error message, on Oreo:

1. Unplug the USB cable of the Android device
2. Plug it in again (same USB port)
3. Run Gradle again
4. That time it worked

Answer (score 0):

Tried every solution I found, but nothing worked. Finally did system settings reset and the problem went away

Comment: Android device factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this by wiping emulator data and open the android folder in Android Studio then run npx react-native run-android